# GitHub SSH test comes back successfully but wrong username

Tags: bash, ssh, git

I set up a SSH keypair as per the GitHub docs. When I test the SSH connection with Git Bash command `ssh -T git@github.com` it works but the message is:

> Hi saito0211! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

`saito0211` is not my GitHub username; I checked and there's nobody on GitHub with that username. There's an instagram account though - looks Japanese.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: This sounds like a matter for GitHub Support.

Comment: There _is_ a user with this username on Github... https://github.com/saito0211

Comment: Might help if you indicated what commands you actually ran.  Yes; You indicated you followed the directions that doesn’t mean you ran the correct commands

Answer (score 4):

GitHub uses the SSH key to verify who you are.  Because all connections use the same username, the only thing that distinguishes users is their public keys.  If you're seeing a username that's unexpected, there are a couple of possibilities:

- The key you're using is not the one you intended.  For example, if I saw that message and I'd just generated and uploaded a key to GitHub, then I'd have to see if there were another key on my computer that was actually created by another person.  If you got your computer from someone else and have not completely reinstalled it, that could be the case.  You can run `ssh -vvv -T git@github.com` to see the public key that is used.
- You generated a keypair but didn't upload the public key to GitHub, and the tool that both you and the other used is insecure and generates weak keys.  GitHub won't allow the same key to be uploaded twice, but if you and this other user both created keys with the same weak PRNG, then you could have generated the same key by accident.  However, such a key would be insecure.
- GitHub has some sort of problem that misidentifies the user.  This is possible, but unlikely, since users would quickly notice and complain.

Note that [the user you were mentioning does exist on GitHub](https://github.com/saito0211).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I inadvertently used the Vagrant ssh key, so no surprise that someone else had already made the same clerical error. Thx github support!